# How to log query String of a SQL statement if it fails to commit?

Tags: java

Sometimes for any reason statement fails to commit to DB correctly. For example if the connection is closed statement.execute() fails.
Does anyone know how to log the statement, in order to identify and log which query string failed to commit successfully?

Comment: What do you mean by:  *for any reason statement fails to commit to DB correctly*? Unclear what you are asking. please read: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be using LoggableStatement Class by IBM:

file address:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-loggable/index.html

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,dbUserName,dbPassword);

StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("SELECT * FROM TABLEx");
LoggableStatement statement = new LoggableStatement(connection,stringBuffer.toString());

try {
    statement.execute();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // write QueryString to a file!
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("fileName", true), "cp1256"));
    out.write(statement.getQueryString());
    out.close();
} finally {
    if (statement != null && !statement.isClosed()) {
        statement.close();
    }
}
```